# TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported in scipy.sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

When executing the following code I get this error `model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mt @ M, Mt @ dx)
TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported`. I guess the problem are the matrix multiplications although `M`, `Mt` and `dx` are all not objects, but `<'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`. The odd thing is that this code runs fine on my computer with python version 3.6.8 but because it's too slow, I transferred the execution to external high-performance computers where I simply copied the python packages and executed it with the same version.

After having looked into the most popular posts concerning this error, I came to realize that none of them solves my problem.

```
# len(template) and fixvertex are some large, positive integers
M = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template)+fixvertex, len(template)))
dx = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template)+fixvertex, 3))

    ...

M = np.real(M)
dx = np.real(dx)
Mt = M.T

model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mt @ M, Mt @ dx)
```

Comment: What Python version is the faster computer using?  This question looks a lot lilke one I recently answered, where using Python 2.7 produced integer `long` values, and object dtype sparse matrices.

Comment: Also version 3.6.8

Comment: In any case, what's the `dtype` of the matrices?

Comment: I don't have access to your high speed computers. If you want help you have to provide the diagnostic information.  We can't do that for you.

Comment: You mean `type(M)`? If so, it's `<'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`. Same goes for the other matrices. And I will do my best to provide the information.

Comment: NO, NO, NO!  Do you understand the difference between `type` and `dtype`?  If not, you may need to do some basic reading about `numpy`.

Comment: Oh okay, I don't understand it but I will read up on it now. As you can probably tell I'm very new to python.

Comment: Sorry, I was being confused and dumb, I do know the difference. Anyway, it's `float64`.

Comment: The way I understand the error message is that the `dtype` of one of the matrices on the fast machine has an object dtype.  How it got that way I don't know.  I can make an object dtype `coo` format, but can't convert it to `lil` or `csr` without raising an error.